# angularjs strange array behaviour, probably related to asynchronous execution?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Difficult to reproduce, so I will try to explain instead.

Within a factory of angularjs I have a function like this

```
angular.module('my').factory('Database', ['$window', 'Raw', function($window, Raw) {
    return {
        read: function() {
```

where Raw is another factory defined below that returns a data string

Then I do this:

```
var lines = [];
lines = Raw.data.split("*");
```

which gives me an array of strings.

The strange behaviour is that it gives an error as lines[0] is undefined.
I can solve this error by adding an alert

```
var lines = [];
lines = Raw.data.split("*");
alert(lines[0])
```

which shows me the expected string. But it does not work if I put a console.log command instead.

So, what's going on??

Cheers,

Comment: please post `Raw.data` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you get `Raw.data` by async way and when you try split it, it still `undefined`.

If `Raw.data` returns promise, use `then()` callback than, something like:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'Database', function($scope, Database) {
   $scope.text =  Database.read();    
}]);

myModule.factory('Database', ['$window', 'Raw', '$q', function($window, Raw, $q) {

  return {
 read: function() {
         var deferred=$q.defer();
        Raw.data().then(function(data) {
            lines = data.split("*");
          deferred.resolve(lines); 
        });
        return deferred.promise;
     }
   }    
}]);

myModule.factory('Raw', ['$window', '$q', function($window, $q) {
    return {
        data: function() {
            var data = "blah * blah";
            var deferred = $q.defer();              
                deferred.resolve(data);               
                return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5gJr/40/)**</kbd>

Comment: I didn't know about promises, very interesting (thanks). Then, Raw is a factory that returns the string "data". In order to make it to return a promise, should I make a function then? Or is there any other way?

Comment: please post the `data` structure and ill post Fiddle example how it should work with promises

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I see that you add a 2nd promise because you cannot leave a factory without a return value, so if you want to return what is inside the "then" function, then you need a promise. Much clearer now, thanks!!